# Using lambda expression to split string two times

Tags: java, lambda

I have a string which looks like this:

`key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=value3
/.../`

I'm interested only in `value` part. I've written the following lambda expression. My aim is to split on new line and then split on `=`. Lambda fails at `.split("=")[1])` instruction with exception `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`.  How do I fix this?

```
List<String> stream = Arrays.stream(license
                .split(System.lineSeparator()
                .split("=")[1]))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Your code is doing `System.lineSeparator().split("=")[1]`. Is that what you meant to write?

Comment: To answer @khelwood's rhetorical question: you don't mean that, because lines aren't separated with an `=`.

Comment: Sorry guys, I don't follow.

Comment: @menteith Your code says `.split(System.lineSeparator().split("=")[1]))`. You are calling `split` on `System.lineSeparator()`.

Comment: OK, now I get it.

Comment: You've changed your question by including one of the provided answers, and then changing the question altogether. If the answer solved your original question, mark it as accepted, and ask a new question. Rolling back.

Comment: I'll ask another question. I didn't copy any answer. @AndyTurner answer (without any code) showed me the right way to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map your results after splitting the lines:

```
String string = "key1=value1\n" + "key2=value2\n" + "key3=value3";
List<String> result = Arrays.stream(string.split(System.lineSeparator()))
                            .map(x -> x.split("=")[1])
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. Could you have a look at my updated post?

Answer (score 0):

Your line breaking and wrapping is confusing. What you actually have written is this:

```
String[] splitLineSep = System.lineSeparator().split("=");
String[] splitLicense = license.split(splitLineSep[1]);
List<String> stream =
    Arrays.stream(splitLicense)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So, you're trying to:

- Split `license`
- On the string obtained by splitting `System.lineSeparator()` on `=`, and taking the part after the `=`.

`System.lineSeparator()` is normally something like `\n` (on Linux, Mac etc) or `\r\n` (on Windows), i.e. something without an `=` sign in it. Hence, if you take the second element of the split array, you'll get an `AIOOBE`, because there is no such element.

You need to think more carefully about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you over-complicating the task?

```
List<String> values = license.replaceAll("^.*=", "")
    .split("\n.*=");
```